# How do I rebind the Emacs help key normally bound to C-h and <f1>?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use `C-h` for deleting, but `<f1>` is hard to type on a MacBook, so how do I make it so that I can type, say, `C-c h <whatever>` instead of `<f1> <whatever>` to access the various help commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(global-set-key "\C-ch" help-map)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I used `global-set-key`, though. (Any particular reason you said `local-set-key`?)

Comment: Oops - I just used `local-set-key` for quick testing, `global-set-key` is what you need for a global change of course!